# How are Hayabusa2's target markers deployed?

Tags: navigation, altitude, hayabusa2

[This presentation](http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sat/hayabusa2/pdf/sat33_fs_23_en.pdf#page=48) talks about 'target markers' which are five soft, reflective balls that are released onto the asteroid's surface prior to landing. They allow the probe to more precisely locate the surface to determine its altitude.

[This diagram](http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sat/hayabusa2/pdf/sat33_fs_23_en.pdf#page=18) shows their location on the craft, but doesn't show what deployment mechanism is used to release them.

[image: Annotated diagram of Hayabusa showing the five target markers on the underside of the craft]

For those interested - the target markers also contain [etchings of names](http://www.planetary.org/get-involved/messages/) submitted to the Planetary Society.

Comment: This is a really classy mission, I love it! Thanks for all the great links.